# Apache POI gets NPE reading xls file

Tags: java, for-loop, apache-poi

I'm trying to read an XLS file into java, which looks something like this

> Column A|Product ID|Number Sold
>   .................|105029    ....|15
>   .................|102930    ....|9
>   .................|203911    ....|29
>   .................|105029    ....|4

where I need to add up the total number of product sold for each product ID and then create a new file with the data sorted. This program is supposed to be flexible, as in there could be 1000 different product ID's or 400. The code below is what I have so far... but there are quite a few problems with it and my lack of java knowledge is making it really frustrating.

The first for loop does not continue, it's stuck at r=1, although the second for loop continues.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class Read {

            public static void readXLSFile() throws IOException{
           InputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream("C:/Sales Data.xls");
                HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
                HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);

                int numRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); 
                //to intialize an array
                int[]idAccum = new int[numRows]; 
                //holds the product id
                int[]saleAccum = new int[numRows]; 
                //holds the total sales per product ID

                        for(int r=1;r<=numRows;r++){ 
                        //iterates through the product ID and matching sales
                            for(int j=r+1;j<numRows+1; j++){
                            HSSFCell rows = sheet.getRow(r).getCell(1);
                            HSSFCell cells = sheet.getRow(r).getCell(2);
                            HSSFCell rows1 = sheet.getRow(j).getCell(1);
                            HSSFCell cells1 = sheet.getRow(j).getCell(2);
                                if(rows==rows1){ 
                            //compares product ids
                                    idAccum[r]=rows1.getNumericCellValue(); 
                        //places product id in element r if rows and rows1 match
                                    saleAccum[r]+=cells.getNumericCellValue(); 
                        //adds number of items sold to corresponding product ID
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println(idAccum[r]); 
                            System.out.println(saleAccum[r]);
                        }   
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        readXLSFile();

            }
}
```

But I'm getting nullpointexceptions.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at Read.readXLSFile(Read.java:29)
>   at Read.main(Read.java:45)
>   Java Result: 1

Comment: Post the exception you are getting

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Read.readXLSFile(Read.java:29)
 at Read.main(Read.java:45)
Java Result: 1

Comment: Don't exactly know what is the problem, as I'm not sure what in line 29, however, your if rows==rows1statement is invalid as you might be comparing the cells objects and not necessarily the values. Why not fetch the values using getNumericCellValue and then compare them using equals?

Comment: You should do this in 2 steps, 1/ read the whole sheet row by row and sum "sold" quantity in a map (key = id, value = sum ; a guava `Multiset` also works) 2/ use the map data. *As is* even if your NPE gets fixed, I fear `ArrayOutOfBoundException`s and bad results (if you have an ID 3 times, the second occurrence gets summed twice with your code). As a side note, always use `equals` for objects in java (not `==`).

Comment: which one is line 29?

Comment: okay i am not sure about your whole logic, but lets assume there are 400 rows total in your sheet, in your first loop you are iterating from 1..400 which is okay but in your nested loop you are iterating from j=r+1 to numRows+1 which based on our assumption should be 401, and guess what row 401 does not exist and hence null pointer. You need to rethink your logic.

Comment: based on what i explained above even if you fix nested loop, if there are total of 400 rows("including header") the outer loop should raise an exception in its last iteration since excel rows are 0 index in apache POI.

Comment: Hmm... the outer loop iterates from 1..400, including 400. The inner loop is j=r+1 to start from the second row, so its 2..400, not including 401, sloppy on my part.

Comment: Thank you!!! You found the NPE, I don't know how I could have missed such a obvious mistake!! Edit: Need to fix this logic now.

Comment: @RC. I've never used maps or multisets and I'll look into it more tomorrow unless someone knows if theres a way to actually fix my logic as it's all over the place right now... thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error: `r` goes up to `numRows`, and `j` starts out at `r + 1` – which during the last iteration is `numRows + 1`. Since there is no content in that row, `getCell(…)` on it will return `null` (as per the API definition). This is where the `NullPointerException` is coming from.

Change

```
for(int r=1;r<=numRows;r++){
```

to

```
for(int r=1;r<numRows;r++){
```

to get rid of the error. Also defensive programming (i.e. checking `getCell(…)` results for `null` is a good idea.